# find missing range from array of ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having array of my class that having Minvalue and Maxvalue property.

Suppose in my array i am having three elements

```
First MinValue=0 and  MaxValue=25
Second MinValue=26 and  MaxValue=50
Third MinValue=75 and  MaxValue=100
```

Minvalue and Maxvalue can be between 0 to 100.

Now I want to find the missing range from above array having three objects.

The missing range in above array is 51 to 75

There can be more than one missing value at that time i want to find the range having min MinValue.

I want to write code in javascript.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Start by writing something. Anything.

Comment: Will you handle overlapping case?  MinValue=0 and  MaxValue=25, MinValue=20 and MaxValue=50?

Comment: The missing range in above array should be 51 to 74?

Comment: Yes derek..the misssing range is 51 to 74

Comment: Also I am handling the overlapping.

Comment: You can view my answer below, it also handle the overlapping case, and disordered min,max value object in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to start something and handle this problem by yourself.

```
var arr = [{ Min :0, Max:25 } , { Min:26, Max:28}, { Min:35, Max:41}, { Min:48, Max:71}];

var range = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    range.push(true); // first set it as missing...
}

for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
{
    for(var j = arr[i].Min ; j <= arr[i].Max ; j++)
    {
        range[j] = false; // loop the array and set it to false
    }
}
var missingPart = '';
var start = false;
for(var i = 0 ; i < range.length ; i++) // loop the range array and build result
{
    if(range[i])
    {
        if(!start)
        {
            start = true;
            if(missingPart)
            {
                missingPart+=", ";
            }   
            missingPart += i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(start)
        {
            start = false;
            missingPart += ("-" + (i-1));
        }
    }
}
if(start)
{
    missingPart += ("-100");
}
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = missingPart
```

Find the jsFiddle result in here : http://jsfiddle.net/gm4HG/2/

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the previous maxValue from the current minValue. The difference should always be 1. Loop through all the values to find the missing range.